# C#: Failed to Delete Multiple Data from Based on Checkbox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem. I want to delete selected data from a `CheckBox` in a `DataGridView`. When I press the delete button, it can not delete my selected data. It says

> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Can anyone help me ?

```
private void JadwalIsi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TampilSelectCheckBox();
        }

private void TampilSelectCheckBox()
        {

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            cb.HeaderText = "Select";
            cb.FalseValue = "0";
            cb.TrueValue = "1";
            cb.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
            cb.Width = 40;
            JadwalisiGV.Columns.Insert(0, cb);
            JadwalisiGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }

    private void DeleteSelectedDataBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in JadwalisiGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                      where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true //error here "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean"
                                                      select row).ToList();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
                {

                        OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(konekpengisian);
                        OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();

                        command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Schedule$] WHERE [WSID] = '" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "'";
                        kon.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        kon.Close();

                        MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil dihapus dari Jadwal Pengisian");

                }

                    TampilJadwal();
                }
```

Comment: so what does `row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value` holds when you debug ?

Comment: How can I know what it holds ?

Comment: Put a break point, run the code, and check :-)

Comment: Knowing your tool will help you using it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx

Comment: There is no problem when I check it in break point. I checked its value and its value is true. I don't know what wrong from my code is

Comment: Why are you converting to boolean here `Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true`??? So you are going to "Convert"."ToBoolean"(SOME STRING) this is what the function is looking for is a string. Yet you supply `row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value` which IS NOT a string, hence your error. Would not `row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true` work without a conversion?